Guy thinks he is being chased by cops
So what is the name of this movie:

So it is a comedy, from the US, around 1995-2000.
Main character is a short guy with blonde hair (short cut), looks like Simon Pegg.
He works in some large company (desk job), he hoped he would get promoted. When his boss promotes someone else, he starts yelling that he will kill him and storms into his office where he finds his boss dead. In addition, he touches the knife he was stabbed with, so he thinks that he can't prove his innocence and starts running from the cops... What he doesn't know is that cops have a videotape of the murder and don't even search for him. Last scene is of a mini statue of liberty.
He eats poison mushrooms and gets sick, also he ate a bunch of expired ham and gets himself in hospital...
He falls in love with a shy country girl.


Is a movie with Pierre Richard?

Hm i thought people will recognize it easily...I will add more details.And no Pierre Richard isn't main character.
